# How do I make my website load a specific file when the URL doesn't specify the file?

Tags: php, html, apache, wamp, wampserver

How do I make my website load a specific file when the URL doesn't specify the file?

I also use WAMP if it helps...

For example...
When the user visits http://mywebsite.com/magicpage/thispage/lmao
I want the user to load the HTML file somefile.html

Comment: apache :  DirectoryIndex  sets the file to show when only a directory is specified.

Comment: perfect, is there anyway to keep the full url requested?
Right now I have it doing this...
Visit http://mywebsite.com/products/supertoy/newtoy
I want this to redirect to display the url http://mywebsite.com/products/supertoy/newtoy in the URL bar, but display the products.html page...

Comment: is the file  in the directory? doc_root/products/supertoy/newtoy/products.html are you looking to rewrite the that request to a different page (product) that isn't in the directory specified by the url.  the you need to look at url rewriting  your questions is a bit unclear

Comment: products.html is in doc_root/products/
I just want to have supertoy/newtoy in the URl so that I can pull those values

Comment: so what you actually want is to use mod_rewrite, and to rewrite the url internally so it displays the products page,and the products page can use the url values to do something   There are tons of exmamples of using mod_rewrite to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you can very easily include the contents of another HTML file within the current page.

```
<?php include_once("path/to/file"); ?>
```

This will still maintain the URL you have given, however, it will contain the contents of the HTML file after where you have put the PHP code.

Pro tip: If you have a header which you use on every page, you can define it on another file, and include it as said here. It reduces the amount of code you have to repeat.

Comment: Ah yes... Didn't mean in this way.